# Polling celery task and return on display

Tags: python, django, celery

I am new to celery. I was following [this example](https://github.com/mikeumus/django-celery-example).

**Views.py**

```
def results(request):
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data['name']
            print 'data', data
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
        #send it to celery  
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render_to_response(
        'results.html',
        {'documents' : documents}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The user would upload a file which would be processed by an engine. In the meantime, i would want the results page to show all jobs that are already completed. I thought of using celery and modifying the tasks.py to process the files. After its completed, the file will be shown as a url for users to download it.

I cannot think of a way to poll this tasks asynchronously to achieve this part. 
thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Django-celery-results](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_celery_results). It is an easy and nice extension of celery that enable you to store your tasks results in django database.
install the extension using :

```
$ pip install -U django-celery-results
```

update settings.py :

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'

INSTALLED_APP = (
    ...
    ...
    django_celery_results
)
```

Create the Celery database tables by performing a database migrations:

```
$ python manage.py migrate django_celery_results
```

Then you can get the list of finished tasks from the database and display it in your view.

```
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult
def tasks_view(request):
    tasks = TaskResult.objects.all()
    template = "tasks.html" 
    return render(request, template, {'tasks': tasks})
```

Define the template "templates/tasks.html"

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>tasks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {% if tasks %}
    <ul>
    {% for task in tasks %}
        <li> {{task.id}} : {{ task.result }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <p>It works!</p>
   {% else %}
    <p>No tasks are available.</p>
   {% endif %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But what's a good way to constantly poll the database in my view? Using a java script?

Comment: Anyway can you give an example as the documentation does not seem to have an example

Comment: you can simply after uploading the file redirect to the tasks view and each time it will pull all results

Comment: After uploading the file it will take a few mins to process at least. So I redirect to the tasks view it will not show it's completed right. I want to consistently poll the task or ideally refresh my page when task is completed without polling

Comment: @aceminer django celery results is the way to go, still to have a real time update on tasks success it's a whole new question. But briefly you need to opt to `websockets` to instantly push updates to your views or you have to implement Long Polling mechanism in your frontend with `ajax`.

Comment: @DhiaTN do you mind pointing me to some resources? Not sure what to check on thanks

Comment: you can start checking here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-provide-a-real-time-update-response-to-a-user-after-he-she-submitted-a-job-to-my-RabbitMQ-Celery-node

Comment: @AymenGasmi Does your code have some issue?. Its on this portion. myapp.models
TASK_MODEL = myapp.models['taskresult']
 The documentation isnt really clear so i cannot really debug what is wrong .

Comment: Hi @aceminer,
In fact you have to define a template and use the correct template path in the view. I have also edited the post. I think now it's clearer and cleaner